# How to expose latest commit's files to public

Tags: git

So I have a shared folder ~myhome/bin where I expose scripts that other people can use. Basically they will add that folder to their path and use the scripts without worrying about the version of the scripts.

How can I do my development in another folder, let's say ~myhome/dev and reflect the latest commit in ~myhome/bin ? Is there a way to use git to push changes to the files in the other folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Just move your development repo to ~myhome/dev and then do `git clone ~myhome/dev ~myhome/bin`, then set up a cron job or git hook to automatically do `git pull` in `~myhome/bin` as needed to get the latest commits.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a worktree checkout:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/some/path/to/myhome/bin git checkout -f
```